# HorizontalStackLayout doesn´t work with images in MAUI on iOS

Tags: xaml, maui, stacklayout

I have a page with a simple grid of 2 rows and 1 column, inside the grid I have an HorizontalStackLayout with 2 images (dotnet_bot). The problem is that on iOS devices the images are not visible but on Android devices they are (see images attached). I also tried with not using the HorizontalStackLayout and instead set the parent grid with 2 columns, but the result is almost the same. I test it with phisical devices (Huawei, Samsung on Android and iPhone 8) and simulated (iPhone 13,14) and there is not differences. Here is my code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="Testapp2.MainPage">

<Grid RowDefinitions="25*,75*" ColumnDefinitions="100*">

    <HorizontalStackLayout HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" Scale="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Source="dotnet_bot.png" Scale="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

The other approach without HorizontalStackLayout

```
<Grid RowDefinitions="25*,75*" ColumnDefinitions="50*,50*">
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="dotnet_bot.png" Scale="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
        <Image Grid.Column="1" Source="dotnet_bot.png" Scale="1" Aspect="AspectFit"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Android]
[image: iPhone]

Comment: this works correctly for me on an iPhone 14 Pro Simulator

Comment: The Grid is directly in the ContentPage? Not inside a ScrollView or other layout? Start over with a new Maui project. Make same change there. Still happen? Then add complete XAML of page to question. Are you targetting .Net 6, or .Net 7? If this is an update from earlier VS, consider deleting all VS versions, reinstalling latest again.

Comment: I am currently using .net 7. There is no more code, only the contentpage section (I updated the question). The problem with start with a new project is that I have a large app so it is the last thing a I wanna try. I tried reinstalling VS but still have the same issue.

Comment: The problem is that on iOS devices the images are not visible. Do you mean only show one image as attached in the iOS device? Besides, in your first snippet code, you forget adding the closing element for the `</HorizontalStackLayout>` which could be the cause.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT the problem is that it is only showing one image, instead of both dotnet_bots. I missed the </HorizontalStackLayout> here but in my original code I do have it.

Comment: @LuisGuzman That's weird. I've tested it on iOS simulator. It works correctly and shows the two dotnet_bots as the first screenshot you attached.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by starting a new project, but only with the robot image provided by MAUI. I noticed that images on iOS do have issues with resizing and fitting correctly. There is an open issue on github about this. [Link](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/13893)

Comment: Glad to see that you've solved it. You can check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it will be helpful for those people who are facing the same issue.